# nested form fields using fields_for is giving error "hash is defined by Active Record... same name"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, stimulusjs

I'm fairly new to rails, so excuse my ignorance. But I currently have a controller which stores "Scan Results" for a theoretical virus scanner.

The Scan Model, has_many Detections, which is a record which holds a Sha256 hash and a type.

the code looks as follows

```
model/scan.rb

class Scan < ApplicationRecord
    has_many :detections, class_name: "detection", foreign_key: "d_id", :dependent => :destroy
    accepts_nested_attributes_for :detections
    validates :hostname, presence: true, uniqueness: { case_sensitive: true }, length: {maximum: 50, minimum: 1}, if: :hostname_not_empty
    
    

    def hostname_not_empty 
        if ( self.hostname != '' || self.hostname.nil? )
            return true
        end
        return errors.add(:scansErr, "Hostname is empty")
    end
end
```

```
model/detections

class Detection < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :scan
  validates :hash, presence: true, length: {maximum: 64, minimum:64}, format: { with: /\b[A-Fa-f0-9]{64}\b/ }
  
  def new () 

  end 
  def new_record
  end
end
```

when I try creating a template for adding new scans to the db, I'm getting this error  `hash is defined by Active Record. Check to make sure that you don't have an attribute or method with the same name`.

I'm using the following template to try and render it all.

```
views/dashboard/form.html.haml

...
= form_for :scans, url: dashboard_scan_create_path(params.to_unsafe_h.slice(:hostname)), :html => {:class => 'flex w-full flex-col scan-form' } do |s|
        %div.flex.w-full.relative
          #{s.text_field :hostname, :class => 'input border border-gray-400 appearance-none rounded w-full px-3 py-3 pt-8 pb-2 my-2 focus focus:border-indigo-600 focus:outline-none active:outline-none active:border-indigo-600' }
          #{s.label :hostname, :class => 'label absolute mb-0 -mt-2 pt-4 pl-3 leading-tighter text-gray-400 text-base mt-2 cursor-text'}
        %div.detections.flex.w-full.my-2{ 'data-controller' => 'detection-form' }
          %div.text-xl.font-bold Detections
          %template{"data-target" => "detection-form.template"}
            = s.fields_for :detections, Detection.new, child_index: "NEW_RECORD" do |d_form|
              = render "detection_fields", form: d_form
...
```

```
views/dashboard/detections-fields.html.haml

= content_tag :div, class: "detection-fields" do
  .input.detection-field-input.d-flex.justtify-content-between.mb-2
    .col-11.pl-0
      = form.fields_for(:detection) do |detection_form|
        = detection_form.text_field :type
        = detection_form.text_field :hash
    .col-1
      = link_to "delete", "#", data: { action: "nested-form#remove_association" }
  = form.hidden_field :_destroy, as: :hidden
```

can anyone help me figure out what I am doing wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is clear in that `ActiveRecord::Core` has defined a method [`hash`](https://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Core/hash) and your model, `Detection`, has a conflicting attribute called `hash`.

The action here is to rename the `hash` attribute of your model to something that isn't already implemented/reserved.

As an example, if you change the model attribute (and the associated code that uses it) to be `sha256` or `sha` it will avoid the conflict.

Comment: Thanks so much!! I wish I had written this hours ago. you've saved me... I dont know why that didnt compute

Comment: All good, hope it works for you @JaSuperior and if it does I'd value you marking the answer as correct!